# Is there a way to check how much data is loaded into a buffer?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop

I am having a little trouble. I am trying to load a 3GB XML file into memory. I have increased my JVM heap size to 10GB but it seems like the file still won't load. Is there a way that I can check percentage of the data I have loaded? Can I add a heap size check to my code when I am loading the XML data into the buffer? Can I use a profiler?

Here is how I am loading the XML file using FSDataInputStream.

```
  val hdfsPath: Path = new Path("./dblp.xml")
  val fs: FileSystem = hdfsPath.getFileSystem(conf)
  val inputStream: FSDataInputStream = fs.open(hdfsPath)

  val xml_load = XML.load(inputStream)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use profiler for this. Either use [VisualVm](https://visualvm.github.io/gettingstarted.html)

or you can even use eclipse memory analyzer

Comment: What would using a profiler let me do? Sorry I've never used one before. From a quick Google search it shows that a profiler is used for debugging but not sure how that would really help me.